# Remove circuit tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit) isn't useful. It seems most people are asking about a circuit design question. But that covers well over half the questions, IMHO. Some questions with the tag are asking about AC wiring "branch circuits". Should we get rid of it?

Edit Oct 6 '11: Same for [circuit-design](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit-design) which isn't much more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I removed these two tags.

There are now a 31 questions in [untagged](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) state that need some cleanup!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I don't see a point to it existing.

Comment: removed, but now we have a few untagged questions...